# Table and longtable centering and caption alignment

Tags: tables, floats, captions, longtable, floatrow

I want to format table and longtable in a special way:

1) table/longtable should be positioned to the center of the page

2) table/longtable caption should be positioned between left and right table/longtable width; also it should be aligned to the left edge of object.

---

Using `\centering` command in `\table` environment satisfies first requirement (longtable is centered by default)

I found a way to satisfy second requirement for table - using `\usepackage{floatrow}` and reformat all tables with `\ttabbox{}{}`. But there are 2 downsides:

- I don't know how to use it with longtable
- `\usepackage{floatrow}` makes longtables to be positioned at left side of page

Minimal example provided.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, final, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
Table should be positioned at the center of the page, and caption should be positioned between left and right edge of table (aligned to left edge)

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{8cm}|}
        \hline
        a & b & c \\ \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Longtable  should positioned at the center of the page, and caption should be positioned between left and right edge of table (aligned to left edge)

\begin{longtable}[h!]{|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}

    \caption{Very,  very, very, very, very, very, very, very  very, very, very, very, very, very, very long caption} \\

    \hline
    a & b \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Short caption} \\
    \hline
    a & b \\ \hline
    \endhead

    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline       
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
    Some string & c \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If your real case is as above, where the widths are known in advance `|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|` then it is easy you can set `\LTcapwidth` to `6cm+3\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep` (or `4\tabcolsep` depending on your definition of width of the table) if your table has dynamically sized `l c r` columns, you need a two pass solution picking up the width from the last run (for which I think there is an answer on site, I'll look...)

Comment: looking at the source floatrow only changes the longtable alignment of left or right alignments of floats generally are requested: \DeclareMarginSet{raggedleft}{\setfloatmargins{\hfil}{}%
  \LTleft=\fill \LTright=\z@}

Comment: For the width of a longtable, I don't seem to have an answer here but see Heiko's code here (I didn't test it but I have faith in his code:-) http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/longtable-tablewidth/1922986

Comment: Heiko's code gives behaviour for longtables exactly as i wanted! Is there similar solution for tables? Cause reformatting all tables with \ttabbox{}{} is a huge pain. Also \usepackage{floatrow} still makes longtables to be positioned at left side of page

Comment: probably, from memory, threeparttable does something related

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/how-to-measure-the-width-of-a-longtable-dynamically-and-use-this-width-in-footer/32549#32549

Comment: Use `threeparttable` for `table`s and Heiko's code (link given in David's comment above) for `longtable`. `\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{8cm}|}
        \hline
        a & b & c \\ \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}`.

Comment: For a table that  splits across pages, you have to use the `threeparttablex` package. It extends the possibilities of `threeparttable`, but take a look at its doc, as the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Ops... One last moment left... Short captions don't aligned to the left edge of table/longtable...