# Long table, caption and notes require adjustment of position - adjustwidth doesn't work

Tags: positioning, longtable, adjustwidth

I have the problem that I would like to hand in an article, however I am required to use the templete the journal provides with multiple restrictions, e.g. a hughe offset on the left side. Now I want to have a table that spans multiple pages (so I cannot use the table environment) and I am not able to adjust it in the correct way. The caption and also the table notes should start on the left side without the offset. The table itself should be centered. Currently the table notes are also not inside a common environment with the table. I hope someone has a solution!

Table 1 shows how it should look like. Table 2 shows how it currently looks like.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
% Text layout
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.023pt}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 2pt \vspace{2mm}}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{2.25in}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{2.25in}

% ltablex package
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout. \\

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.25in}{0in}
        \centering
        \caption{
            {\bf Table caption... This is how it should look like.}}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf Heading 1} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf Heading 2}\\
            \hline
            $cell1 row1$ & cell2 row 1 & cell3 row 1 & cell4 row 1 & cell5 row 1 & cell6 row 1 & cell7 row 1 & cell8 row 1\\ \hline
            $cell1 row2$ & cell2 row 2 & cell3 row 2 & cell4 row 2 & cell5 row 2 & cell6 row 2 & cell7 row 2 & cell8 row 2\\ \hline
            $cell1 row3$ & cell2 row 3 & cell3 row 3 & cell4 row 3 & cell5 row 3 & cell6 row 3 & cell7 row 3 & cell8 row 3\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
            \begin{flushleft} Table notes...
            \end{flushleft}
        \label{table1}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}%{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l+l|l|l|l|l|l|@{}}
    \caption{
    \bf{Table caption... This is how it looks like.}} \\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 1} \vline & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 2} \vline \\
Heading 1                 & Heading 2   & Heading 3   & Heading 4   & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\ 
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{7}{l}
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 1} \vline & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 2} \vline \\
Heading 1                 & Heading 2   & Heading 3   & Heading 4   & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\ 
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
    Text                   & 1         & 2     & 3          & 4       & 5       & 6             \label{table2}
\end{longtable}
Table notes...


\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your `longtable` is to wide that can be fit in text width. make column headers narrower.

Comment: You specify `letterpaper`, which sets the total *page* width to 8.5". You then specify both a left-hand margin of 2.75" and a text block width of 5.25". This implies that the right-hand margin is only 0.5". Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mirco Yes, it's on intention. I used the template of the journal.

Comment: @Zarko I know, It won't be possible to make it smaller as the content of the table will need the full page.

Comment: @user3410101, that was not clear in your question. it seems that Ulrike better guess, what you is the problem with your `longtable`. now i accordingly correct my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the longtable in the margin by using a negative `\LTleft`. The caption can be moved with the `caption` package and negative margin too:

```
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{margin=-2.25in}
\setlength{\LTleft}{-2.25in}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution with the caption. I didn't think about the caption package! The caption is nicely set to the correct position now. However the table is at the same position using the 2.25 in. But I am required to set it centered unfortunately. Do you also have a solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: You can retrieve the width of the longtable and then use this to calculate the needed shift value.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32549/2388.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**
after clarification of question in your comment below quation is now clear that you also like to have wide `longtable` which not protrude into right margin. one solution for this is provided in [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) answer below, so i add here some changes which might like (long table has the same width as table in `adjustwidth` environment):

see if the following changes in your mwe is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
% Text layout
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
%\textwidth 5.25in
%\textheight 8.75in

% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,
            justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.023pt}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 2pt \vspace{2mm}}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{2.25in}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{2.25in}

% ltablex package
\usepackage{makecell, % for two line column headers, macro  \thead{...\\...}
            ltablex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}

This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout. \\

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.25in}{0in}
        \centering
        \caption{Table caption... This is how it should look like.}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                    |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Heading 1}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{Heading 2}}\\
            \hline
            $cell1 row1$ & cell2 row 1 & cell3 row 1 & cell4 row 1 & cell5 row 1 & cell6 row 1 & cell7 row 1 & cell8 row 1\\ \hline
            $cell1 row2$ & cell2 row 2 & cell3 row 2 & cell4 row 2 & cell5 row 2 & cell6 row 2 & cell7 row 2 & cell8 row 2\\ \hline
            $cell1 row3$ & cell2 row 3 & cell3 row 3 & cell4 row 3 & cell5 row 3 & cell6 row 3 & cell7 row 3 & cell8 row 3\\ \hline
        \end{tabular*}

        \raggedright
        Table notes...
        \label{table1}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

{\setlength{\LTleft}{-2.25in}
 \setlength{\LTright}{0in}
 \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth+4.5in\relax}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}

    \caption{Table caption... This is how it looks like.}
    \label{tab:my long table}\\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Top Heading 1}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Top Heading 2}        \\
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Top Heading 1} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Top Heading 2}        \\
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7   \\

    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6
\end{longtable}
}
Table notes...

\end{document}
```

which gives (top part of first page):

[image]

(top part of second page):

[image]

- regarding table notes, see if `threparttable` (or `threparttablex`) can improve writing table notes.
- more professional look of table you will obtain with use rules from package `booktabs` and omit vertical rules:

[image]

changes in above mwe are:

```
...
\usepackage{booktabs,
            ltablex}

\begin{document}

This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout.
This is just a dummy text to show the general text layout. \\

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.25in}{0in}
        \centering
        \caption{Table caption... This is how it should look like.}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     lll lll ll}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Heading 1}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Heading 2}}\\
            \midrule
            $cell1 row1$ & cell2 row 1 & cell3 row 1 & cell4 row 1 & cell5 row 1 & cell6 row 1 & cell7 row 1 & cell8 row 1\\ 
            $cell1 row2$ & cell2 row 2 & cell3 row 2 & cell4 row 2 & cell5 row 2 & cell6 row 2 & cell7 row 2 & cell8 row 2\\ 
            $cell1 row3$ & cell2 row 3 & cell3 row 3 & cell4 row 3 & cell5 row 3 & cell6 row 3 & cell7 row 3 & cell8 row 3\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}

        \raggedright
        Table notes...
        \label{table1}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

{\setlength{\LTleft}{-2.25in}
 \setlength{\LTright}{0in}
 \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth+4.5in\relax}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      lll lll l
                      }
    \caption{Table caption... This is how it looks like.}
    \label{tab:my long table}\\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 1}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 2}        \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Top Heading 1} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Top Heading 2}        \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7   \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    \addlinespace
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    \addlinespace
    Text        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6\\
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution! Unfortunately I am not allowed to make the changs you suggested and the tables are required (at least for submission) to have all rules. Regarding the table notes I will have a look to the packages you suggested.

Comment: @user3410101, than you can consider first solution, where tables have rules :).