# rotate table or not, depending on its width

Tags: longtable, ifthenelse

I build a Tex file in C# and then compile to PDF.

How would I rotate a table sideways if it is to wide for portrait?

So the actual, displayed width is only known AFTER the table is generated in C#..

I'm trying to define the whole table in a \def in the preamble and then if/then/else in \begin{document}.
Can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=50mm, right=50mm, top=50mm, bottom=50mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=2pt}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\def\foo{   
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\makecell{$f_y$\\ \si{\newton\per\milli\meter\squared}}}
    \begin{longtable}{ccr}
    % \getlongtablewidth % does not work, IMHO
    \caption{Material data}\label{tab:Material data}\\
    \toprule[2pt]
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Materials}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}  
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotcell{Code}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotcell{Name}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{r}{\rotcell{$f_y$\\ $[\si{\newton\per\milli\meter\squared}]$}}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{Material data (Continued)}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Materials}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}  
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotcell{Code}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{r}{\rotcell{$\rho$\\ $[\si{\kilogram\per\cubic\meter}]$}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{r}{\rotcell{$f_y$\\ $[\si{\newton\per\milli\meter\squared}]$}}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule(lr){3-3}  
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{ Continued on next page}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    S235 & 1.15&235 \\
    \bottomrule[1pt]
    \end{longtable}
    }
    
\begin{document}
    % what would the \if\then\else construction look like?
    %\if --some conditional expression ---
    \begin{landscape}
    \foo
    \end{landscape}
    %\else
    \foo
    %\endif
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can measure a longtable: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32549/2388

Comment: Have you tried that?

And what about the if/else construction in the \begin{document} part?

Comment: well it is my answer and yes I used that code in various places. Once you have the width you can compare it e.g. with \textwidth.